# What file or folder contains the contents for the Dash?

Tags: unity-dash

I have deinstalled a package (epiphany) which showed up thrice in the dash. Now, one of the application-icons is gone, yet two remain.

I want to know where to start looking into this problem: how does the Dash application-lense determine its contents? And where (if at all) is that saved or cached?

`lsof -c unity` and the likes, may list the file(s) or folder I am looking for, but wading through all that content is just too much work :)

Comment: `lsof -c unity and the likes, may list the file(s) or folder I am looking for, but wading through all that content is just too much work` ... `grep`?

Comment: sure. If you tell me what to grep for :) (which is, the name of the dir, file or cache that contains the entries)

Comment: Try `ls /usr/share/applications | grep epiphany`.

Comment: `/usr/share/applications` does not contain anything referring to epiphany (I grepped all content), nor does `/usr/share/application-registry`. I suspect these entries lie below my $HOME.

Comment: what about `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: MHC has modified the existing answer so you may as well accept that one!

Comment: Please modify your question! dash gets it's contents from zeitgeist's sqlite db. And that should be the answer to your correct question, but you seem to be looking for something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application launchers - or rather their respective `.desktop` files - are stored under these directories:

- `/usr/share/applications` - all users
- `$HOME/.local/share/applications` - your user

If you look through these you should be able to find the culprit.

---

Another option are GUI menu editors. Out of the ones available I prefer [MenuLibre](https://launchpad.net/menulibre), a pretty new project originally coded for the Ubuntu App Showdown. You can install the latest release from the developer's PPA by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:menulibre-dev/devel && apt-get update
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

MenuLibre allows you to easily browse through your menu entries, identify duplicates and easily delete them:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, interesting information, but not really what I asked: I wanted to know a specific "application" entry, not an entire lense.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're right. I read your question wrong.

Comment: @berkes I completely overhauled my answer in accordance with your actual question.